# An Incident Between the Prophet and Aisha

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I heard the following:

> Hazrat Aisha donated some the whole meat of an animal they owned
>   except a small part, and the Prophet came she said that she gave away
>   the meat for the sake of Allah, but kept his favorite part for him,
>   and the Prophet gave this profound reply: In fact we kept the part you
>   gave and just lost the part you kept.

I searched with numerous keywords with no avail. Would anybody know the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hadith you are asking about is most likely the one that was documented in Jami' at-Tirmidhi as a hassan hadith (and has been elevated to authentic by some scholars):

> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ بَشَّارٍ، حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، عَنْ سُفْيَانَ، عَنْ أَبِي إِسْحَاقَ، عَنْ أَبِي مَيْسَرَةَ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، أَنَّهُمْ ذَبَحُوا شَاةً فَقَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ مَا بَقِيَ مِنْهَا ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَتْ مَا بَقِيَ مِنْهَا إِلاَّ كَتِفُهَا ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ بَقِيَ كُلُّهَا غَيْرَ كَتِفِهَا ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو عِيسَى هَذَا حَدِيثٌ صَحِيحٌ ‏.‏ وَأَبُو مَيْسَرَةَ هُوَ الْهَمْدَانِيُّ اسْمُهُ عَمْرُو بْنُ شُرَحْبِيلَ ‏.
>
> Abu Maisarah narrated from 'Aishah that they had slaughtered a sheep, so the Prophet (s.a.w) said: "What remains of it?" She said: "Nothing remains of it except its shoulder." He said: "All of it remains except its shoulder."
>
> <sub>— [Jami' at-Tirmidhi, Vol. 4, Book 11, Hadith 2470](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/726530)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Assalam alaikum,
Allah SWT knows best

Rassoul Allah swallallah aleyhi wassallam slaughtered a sheep and He asked 
Hazrat Aisha to go and share this meat as sadaqa.
She finished giving do sabilillah but was left a shoulder.
She came back to the Prophet Rassoul Allah swallallah aleyhi wassallam ans told him of that left piece of the sheep.
They cooked and are it
 and the Prophet gave this profound reply: In  fact all what you gave will be gained in Aakhira while the part we eat is just lost(no hassanat for it coz they eat and it was not counted as sadaqa w Allahu a3lam

Comment: Would it be possible to answer the original question please: *Would anybody know the source?*

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. This answer could benefit from provided external sources to support your answer.