# Authenticity of hadith where Meat turned to stone?

Tags: hadith, reference-request, meat

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

I found a narration in '***Behasti Zewar***' in which there has been narated the following without any credentials or sources.

> "Once Hazrat Umme Salma, wife of the prophet Muhammmad( pbuh) received
>   some meat from somewhere as a gift. The Prophet Muhammad was fond of
>   meat, so she decided to keep it for him. In the meantime a beggar came
>   to the door and asked for something in alms.
>
> Hazrat Umme Salma sought blessings for him which meant that there was
>   nothing to give. The beggar went away. After some time Prophet
>   Muhammad came and asked Hazrat Umme Salma for something to eat. She
>   asked the maid to bring the meat. When the maid went to bring the meat
>   it was not on the shelf and in its place a stone was found. The whole
>   incident was brought to the knowledge of the Prophet Muhammad(pbuh).
>   The Prophet replied that because it was not given to a needy person it
>   had turned to stone."

Is this authentic? Please give sources if it is.

Comment: I've never heard this nor about the source you are quoting which doesn't sound Arabic ...

Comment: The closest that come to mind is discussed in [An incident between the prophet and Aisha](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44915/an-incident-between-the-prophet-and-aisha?rq=1)

Comment: This Hadith is from Sunan al-Kubra by Bayhaqi if that helps narrowing the search for authenticity.

Comment: It can be found in [Dalaa’il an-Nubuwwah](https://shamela.ws/book/7478/2763) of al-Bayhaqi.